# Unwanted Space Between <header> and <nav>

Tags: css, html, whitespace, semantic-markup

I have the following HTML5 code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 120%;
}
header, nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
header {
  border-color: red;
}
img.mainpicture {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img class="mainpicture" src="http://s29.postimg.org/ajjbb0n07/apic.jpg" alt="A picture"/></header><nav>Navigation area.</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain why there is about 5 pixels of empty space between the `<header>` and the `<nav>` content, and how can I remove it?

By adding

```
header {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

to the CSS file, the height of the white space is extended by one pixel, so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the padding of `<header>`.

EDIT: I would like to do it without using `<nav style="position: relative; top:-7px;">`.

Comment: vertical-align: top; on .mainpicture should fix this https://jsfiddle.net/Lsszpbhh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set display block on the image for fixing fitting issues.

```css
body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 120%;
}
header,
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img.mainpicture {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="mainpicture" src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/960/200/2" alt="A picture" />
</header>
<nav>
  Navigation area.
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the inner elements having a `margin`, that is protruding outside! And also since you have an `<img />`, give a `display: block;` to it. Try `overflow: hidden;` for both `header`, `nav`:

```css
header, nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header img {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! "display: block;" for the img is already enough to fix it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
img.mainpicture{
.....................
.....................
vertical-align: top;
}
```

That will fix the issue:)

Answer (score -1):

Set the property `margin-bottom` equal to zero.

`margin-bottom: 0;`

Comment: `margin` is already set to 0 for both `header` and `nav`.